# Center of a group $G$, when the commutator subgroup has index 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group, $M=G^{'}Z(G)$, $|\frac{G}{M}|=2$ and there is an element $x\in G$ such that $|C_G(x)|=4$. Is it true that $|Z(G)|>1$ ? ($G^{'}$ is the commutator subgroup and $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$).

Comment: Why should it be?

Comment: No it is not necessarily true. Why should it be?

Comment: @ Derek Holt: If $G$ be a solvable group, then the answer is no again?

Comment: That is correct, the answer is also no for solvable groups. (But I voted to close the question for lack of context.)

Comment: This might be [some context](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677046/finite-groups-g-satisfying-property-p-n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can help

$$G=S_4\;,\;\;M=G'Z(G)=A_4\cdot1=A_4\;,\;\;|G/M|=2, \;\text{and}\;\left|C_G\left\{(1\;2)\right\}\right|=4 $$

Observe that $\;S_4\;$ is solvable, in accord to Derek's comment.

Comment: Yes that is the example I had in mind. There are also (solvable) examples of order $24m$ for any odd number $m$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you.